# Error de sintaxis al poner un numero como nombre de tabla mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hola estoy realizando el siguiente query con la variable

```
$fechaActual = date('dmy');
```

dasd

```
$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE ".$fechaActual." (id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)")
```

Este me da error de sintaxis pero si hago esto:

```
$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE a".$fechaActual." (id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)")
```

funciona... (agregue una a junto a la variable)

pd: si puedo crear una tabla con solo números como phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema no es que tus tablas son de numeros. El problema es que son unicamente numeros.

Un identificador (el nombre de una tabla es uno) en MySQL debería consistir de los caracteres `[0-9,a-z,A-Z$_]`.

**Pero:**

"Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits." *dice la documentación de identificadores en MySQL*

Tienes que escapar el nombre de la tabla si quieres usar puros números. Para mantener cosas más simples, te recomiendo otro esquema de nombrar tus tablas.

Comment: ummm pense que el problema era que solo eran números pero probe con phpmyadmin a crear una tabla con números y me la creo sin problemas entonces ¿hasta que punto eso que mencionas es así? por que también investigue sobre si habían restricciones al nombrar y lo único que encontré fueron "recomendaciones" o "estándar" pero nada como reglas intrínsecas del sistema :o

Comment: Phpmyadmin enmascara el entrecomillado, ppr cierto ayudando a confundir al usuario final.

Comment: @CristoferFuentes [especificación de identificadores en ingles](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) <- lamentablemente no hay una versión oficial en español.